# Get RegionInfo by country name?

Tags: c#, regions, regioninfo

I want to be able to get `RegionInfo` by doing the following:

```
new RegionInfo("United Kingdom");
```

but this throws an exception and says that it is not recognised.

This [page on RegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa328577%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) says that an exception is thrown if 'name is not a valid country/region name'.

And yet this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28VS.80%29.aspx) specifies a list of predefined regions used by the class that and contains `United Kingdom`, so why doesn't creating a new `RegionInfo` with country name work?

Comment: Please, read the documentation well: The RegionInfo name is one of the two-letter codes defined in ISO 3166 for country/region.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
  var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));
  var englishRegion = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName.Contains(name));
```

If you want to get `RegionInfo` by the country name, you could get an `IEnumerable<RegionInfo>` and then filter based on the `EnglishName` as above. This gives you the ability to populate things such as comboboxes too.

Comment: But it would be null since the `EnglishName` is "English (United Kingdom)" ;-) So you might want to use `FirstOrdefault(r => r.EnglishName.Contains(name))`

Comment: @LukeHennerley: It will be still `null` but now without an exception. +1 anyway since `Contains` instead of `==` would be too generous.

Comment: It works for me, EnglishName is appearing as "United Kingdom"

Comment: @Tyler I thought it would work too, the english name for `GB` on the `MSDN` is simply `United Kingdom`

Answer (score 3):

That same page you linked also says:

> The RegionInfo name is one of the two-letter codes defined in ISO 3166
>   for country/region. Case is not significant; however, the Name, the
>   TwoLetterISORegionName, and the ThreeLetterISORegionName properties
>   return the appropriate code in uppercase.

The codes are on the page, and `GB` appears to be the 2 letter code for the UK (it's in code order to be difficult searching!). So try this:

```
new RegionInfo("GB");
```

Or if you're using .NET 2.0+, it's recommended you use the full culture name:

```
new RegionInfo("en-GB");
```

Comment: The Original Poster linked an old version of the spec. Since .NET 2.0 it is recommended to use e.g. `"en-GB"` instead of just `"GB"`.

Comment: Great. The other possibilities with GB are: _Welsh (United Kingdom)_ `"cy-GB"` and _Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)_ `"gd-GB"`.

Answer (score 2):

From *MSDN*;

> A string that contains a two-letter code defined in ISO 3166 for
>   country/region.

`UNITED KINGDOM` looks ok on [Country names and code elements](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) on the ISO website.

> GB    UNITED KINGDOM

Try with;

```
new RegionInfo("GB");
```

Comment: The Original Poster linked an old version of the spec. Since .NET 2.0 it is recommended to use e.g. `"en-GB"` instead of just `"GB"`.

Answer (score 1):

If I navigate to the constructor the summary I see in Visual Studio says:

> **name**: A string that contains a two-letter code defined in ISO 3166 for
>   country/region.-or-A string that contains the culture name for a
>   specific culture, custom culture, or Windows-only culture. **If the
>   culture name is not in RFC 4646 format**, your application should
>   specify the **entire culture name instead of just the country**/region.

The entire culture name would be 'en-GB'.

Or you could use 'GB'

Comment: There's [a newer version of the doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atwc2921.aspx) compared to what the original question links to. It is clearly recommended to use a full specific culture, like `"en-GB"`, instead of just `"GB"`. We don't know what version of the framework is used by the Original Poster, but he should certainly go with `new RegionInfo("en-GB")`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MSDN page:

`A string containing one of the two-letter codes defined in ISO 3166 for country/region.`

You need the ISO 3166 code for the UK, not the name of the country.

Here's the [code you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#GB).

Answer (score 0):

Note this comment from the metadata for the parameter `name` which explains the change from .NET Framework 2.0 on:

```
    //     A string containing one of the two-letter codes defined in ISO 3166 for country/region.-or-Beginning
    //     in .NET Framework version 2.0, a string containing the culture name for a
    //     specific culture, custom culture, or Windows-only culture. If the culture
    //     name is not in RFC 4646 format, your application should specify the entire
    //     culture name, not just the country/region.
```