# Convert country name to country code

Tags: c#

[Basing on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262021/get-regioninfo-by-country-name) i would like to convert a users' nationality selected from a combobox to it's two letter country code. If a user selects "South Africa" as their country i need to convert it to "SA". I tried the code below and it throw a nullreference exception.

```
var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));

var english_region = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName == this.Nationality);

string code = english_region.TwoLetterISORegionName;
```

Comment: You will need to debug your code. See the marked duplicate on how to do this.

Comment: Where exactly is the null reference exception thrown? Which variable is null? Use the debugger, set breakpoints, inspect variables, compare actual values against expected vaues.